# How to delete object file in S3 from PHP

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am trying to delete file from Amazon S3.

PHP Code:

```
<?php

$file = $_POST['file'];
var_dump($file);
include('s3_configExpansion.php');

ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);

// File upload into S3
if ($s3->deleteObject($bucket, $file))
{
    $msg = "S3 Delete Successful."; 
}

echo 'Deleted';

?>
```

I used this code for deleting. I have received the file at `$file` variable.

```
$file = 'folder/subfolder/filename.apk';
```

But file is not deleting from S3.

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: Refer to this question, it might help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605878/delete-a-file-from-s3-bucket#:~:text=php'%3B%20use%20Aws%5CS3,Key'%20%3D%3E%20%24keyname%20))%3B