# Delete a file from s3 bucket

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-s3

I've created an upload and download service in php-symfony2. This is working fine. Now I want to delete the uploaded file. Any Example?

Note: No data storing to database tables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Deleting One Object (Non-Versioned Bucket)**

1. Create instance of S3 client using *Aws\S3\S3Client class factory()*.

> $s3 = S3Client::factory();

2. Execute the Aws\S3\S3Client::deleteObject() method with bucket name and a key name.

   $result = $s3->deleteObject(array(
   'Bucket' => $bucket,
   'Key'    => $keyname
   ));

If versioning is enabled DELETE MARKER Will be added. ([References](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DeletingObjects.html))

**EXAMPLE**

```
<?php

    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    use Aws\S3\S3Client;
    $s3 = S3Client::factory();
    
    $bucket = '*** Your Bucket Name ***';
    $keyname = '*** Your Object Key ***';
    
    $result = $s3->deleteObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key'    => $keyname
    ));
```

More References can be found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DeletingOneObjectUsingPHPSDK.html).

Comment: Let me try it .

Comment: how we can delete object without providing any key and secret?

Comment: @HiteshRanaut lol. asking this is like how to drive a car "without" petrol.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping using CNG or electricity. :D

Comment: but yeah you are right I don't remember why I have added above comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **deleteObject()** method, refer the [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DeletingOneObjectUsingPHPSDK.html).

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$s3 = S3Client::factory();

$bucket = '*** Your Bucket Name ***';
$keyname = '*** Your Object Key ***';

$result = $s3->deleteObject(array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'    => $keyname
));
```

Answer (score 2):

After lot of solution i tried i found the solution that works for me perfectly.

```
$s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
$s3->delete('filename');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the aws s3 delete API method which delete the uploaded file. you can achieve it like below.

use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$s3 = new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);

$s3->deleteObject("bucketname", `filename`);

Answer (score 1):

This Code Worked For me.

```
    $s3Client = new S3Client([
    'version'     => 'latest',
    'region'      => 'your region',
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => '**AWS ACCESS KEY**',
        'secret' => '**AWS SECRET ACCESS KEY**',
    ],
    ]);

    try {
    $result = $s3Client->deleteObject(array(
        'Bucket' => '**YOUR BUCKET**',
        'Key'    => "videos/file.mp4"
        )); 
        return 1;
    } catch (S3Exception $e) {
        return $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Arsalan's answer doesn't appear to work anymore. What worked for me, using access and secret keys was:

```
    $this->s3 = new S3Client([
      'driver' => 's3',
      'version' => 'latest',
      'region'  => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
      'credentials' => [
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'), 
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
      ]
    ]);

    $this->s3->putObject([
      'Bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),  
      'Key'    => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
      'Body'   => $body,
      'Key'    => $key
    ]);
```