# deleting files from s3 using laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

I want to delete files from my bucket programmatically but it is not happening

I have the below code

```
$s3 = \Storage::disk('s3');
$existingImagePath = $studentPortfolios[$i]->portfolio_link; // this returns the path of the file stored in the db
$s3->delete($existingImagePath);
```

But this is not deleting the files from the bucket

I have to write objects permission to the bucket for everyone for the time being as I am running this from my local setup.

Please note:- I am able to upload files but deleting is not working

Any advice on this will be really helpful.

Comment: Edit question with response object you are getting from S3. There is message about what happened.

Comment: @Dhaval Chheda may be missing delete permission in bucket other wise your path is not proper but your code is right

Comment: @Tpojka there is no message it just does not delete

Comment: You should always get some response, wether there was an error wether there was successful action. Try with this [package](https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/docs/adapter/aws-s3/) or set last line in try catch block.

Comment: Here is the solution that works perfect for me [Delete file from s3 bucket in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61930279/5783617)

Answer (score 5):

Its just like file deletion from disk. Check this to the laravel document: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#deleting-files

```
 $imageName = $studentPortfolios[$i]->portfolio_link; // this returns the file name stored in the DB
 \Storage::disk('s3')->delete('s3_folder_path/'. $imageName);
```

Make sure file has permision to delete. If not give the permission from s3 by selecting the file or directory and select Make Public option from action in s3.

Answer (score 1):

I have done with this below code.

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

    $bucket  =  "bucket";
    $keyname = "keyname";
    $s3 = new S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'region'
    ]);
    $result = $s3->deleteObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key'    => $keyname
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to deleting the files in the bucket using the AWS s3 cli command and see if it works ?

> Ex: aws s3 rm s3://bucket-name/ --recursive

If it works then may be you need to fix the issue in your code.

Comment: directly it works.. so there is something in the code but don't know what and how to fix it